# Возможно ли вытянуть вычисляемую формулу из динамической .so библиотеки?

Tags: библиотеки, декомпиляция, reverse-engineering

Есть .so библиотека, в которой есть две функции. Эти функции выполняют вычисление неких математических формул, которые необходимо узнать. Возможно это как-то сделать? Возможно получить ее ассемблерный код и восстановить формулы?

https://mega.nz/#!Est2CShD!lKVHiXkClhK6sSTvKTi4UOrhQowq_Syo0zhpgn_Bi8s

Answer (score 3):

```
objdump -d libSwimEnergy.so > libSwimEnergy.S
```

Получаете что-то вроде (фрагмент, но там немного, около 300 строк всего):

```
00000000000005f0 <ComputeEnergyLap>:
 5f0:   44 0f b6 54 24 10       movzbl 0x10(%rsp),%r10d
 5f6:   41 bb 64 00 00 00       mov    $0x64,%r11d
 5fc:   0f b7 c9                movzwl %cx,%ecx
 5ff:   40 0f b6 f6             movzbl %sil,%esi
 603:   40 0f b6 ff             movzbl %dil,%edi
 607:   45 0f b6 c9             movzbl %r9b,%r9d
 60b:   45 0f b6 c0             movzbl %r8b,%r8d
 60f:   44 89 d0                mov    %r10d,%eax
 612:   44 89 54 24 10          mov    %r10d,0x10(%rsp)
 617:   41 0f af c3             imul   %r11d,%eax
 61b:   44 0f b7 da             movzwl %dx,%r11d
 61f:   89 c2                   mov    %eax,%edx
 621:   c1 fa 1f                sar    $0x1f,%edx
 624:   41 f7 fb                idiv   %r11d
 627:   0f b7 d0                movzwl %ax,%edx
 62a:   e9 d1 fe ff ff          jmpq   500 <ComputeEnergyCurrentLength@plt>
 62f:   90                      nop
```

Вполне пригодно для изучения.

Comment: я бы предложил IDA PRO. Платная правда, но бесплатных возможностей должно хватить.

Comment: Что здесь поможет - это плагин HexRays, который ассемблер превращает в некий Си-подобный псевдокод.